# Changing flyway migration files after setting new baseline

Tags: java, database, flyway

I have flyway integrated in one of my projects. I have many migrations and it takes a long time to migrate a new empty database, mainly because there are seed data added along the way as well. Now I want to change that. Unfortunately those migrations were already pushed to production (and yes, at some point the seed data was migrated there as well).

My idea was to set a baseline for the current version of the production system and clean up the old migrations afterwards: Squash the schema-migrations and move the seed- and test-data to a new location, that is not deployed to production.

Now my questions are:

1. How can I set a baseline in my production database, without affecting all others? Call `flyway baseline ...` on the database directly? Or can I use any kind of special migration file? Maybe write the baseline line directly to the `schema_version` table of the database? How would such a query look like?
2. My newest migration is `V4_6_3__...`. So my baseline needs to be on `V5__...`? Or is `V4__...` enough and all migrations with the same major version are included?
3. When the baseline is set, is it possible/save to add, edit, and remove migrations, older than the baseline, without breaking my production database on the next migration task?

Sorry for the basic questions, but it seems to me, that the flyway documentation is no help at all...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sry for the late answer. I have done a pretty similar thing to the one [@markdsievers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40652562/6828631) suggested:

I assured that the production environment was at least on version `X` (`flyway.setTarget(X)`). Then I changed to a new schema version table (`flyway.setTable('temporary_schema_version')`) and ran a single migration, that deleted the old table. Afterwards I changed the schema version table back to the original one, set a baseline to version `Y > X` and ran another migration that deleted the temporary table.

Now I can edit/squash/delete all migrations with a version lower than `Y` without crashing my production-deployment.

Answer (score 2):

I went through a very similar scenario, and even wrote our own in house tool called the "Rebaser" which does most of what you want. Our main motivation was to upgrade from Flyway 3.x to 4.3 but we also had a large history which needed to be squashed. The gist of it is this:

1. Squash all your migrations into however many makes sense. I typically have a `V2__base_ddl.sql` and `V3__base_data.sql` (Flyway can use the first couple of version numbers for schema creation etc). This is the manual part.
2. Your rebase tool detects the old `schema_version` table and deletes it.
3. Your rebase tool then runs `init` + `migrate` with your new baseline version set.
4. Rebase tool leaves behind a footprint (a rebase key in a custom table) that indicates it has been done.

For my integration test builds (that spin up a vanilla database and migrate forwards to latest) I add an extra folder of test data SQL scripts using Flyways `locations` argument, thus ensuring I have test data for integration tests but not in any non-test environments.

Our Rebaser is just a thin wrapper around the `Flyway` Java API, adding in the prestep to do the rebase if configured and then delegate to Flyway.

Flyway doesn't have a notion of rebasing but it's something we have found is necessary to do as your history gets large and contains obsolete data / DDL. So far this system has worked flawlessly.